# JAXB Generate schema that has an attribute group

Tags: xml, jaxb

Is it possible to use JAXB annotations to generate a schema with an attribute group? If so, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) does not define a way to output an attribute group into a generated schema.

---

### Starting from an XML Schema

Below is a sample XML schema with two complex types that reference the same attribute group.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <attributeGroup name="my-attribute-group">
        <attribute name="att1" type="string"/>
        <attribute name="att2" type="int"/>
    </attributeGroup>

    <complexType name="foo">
        <attributeGroup ref="tns:my-attribute-group"/>
        <attribute name="foo-att" type="string"/>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="bar">
        <attributeGroup ref="tns:my-attribute-group"/>
        <attribute name="bar-att" type="string"/>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

**Generated Model**

In the generated classes below we see that the attributes from the attribute group are treated the same way as the attributes that were defined within the complex type.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "foo-att")
    protected String fooAtt;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att1")
    protected String att1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att2")
    protected Integer att2;

}
```

and

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "bar")
public class Bar {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "bar-att")
    protected String barAtt;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att1")
    protected String att1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att2")
    protected Integer att2;

}
```

---

### Starting from Java Classes

> If not, why not?

Now that we know that attributes from attribute groups are simply treated the same way as regular attributes are extra metadata would be needed to indicate that they are part of the same attribute group.  Care would need to be taken to ensure that as the `Foo` and `Bar` classes evolve that there separate definitions of the same attribute group don't diverge over time resulting in an error.  Since the same XML document can be represented by XML schemas with or without attribute groups JAXB has opted for the simpler less error prone option of not providing a standard way to generate them.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "foo-att")
    protected String fooAtt;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att1", fictionalPropertyAttributeGroup="my-attribute-group")
    protected String att1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att2", fictionalPropertyAttributeGroup="my-attribute-group")
    protected Integer att2;

}
```

and

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "bar")
public class Bar {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "bar-att")
    protected String barAtt;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att1", fictionalPropertyAttributeGroup="my-attribute-group")
    protected String att1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att2", fictionalPropertyAttributeGroup="my-attribute-group")
    protected Integer att2;

}
```